# Set a limit occurrence for a value in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

So let's say i have a table that has a column "id_author" , i'd like to set a limit for the occurrence of the same value ; example : can't have more than 3 same "id_author" values so when i insert the 4th one it's refused.

Is there a way to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `trigger` before insert, that will throw a signal in case it violates your condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tooManyRecords
BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE counter INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM yourTable
WHERE id_author = NEW.id_author;

IF counter >= 3 THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'there are already 3 records for the provided id';
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much , that's exactly what i wanted to learn how to do :)